# cassandra nodes are unresponsive and "Native-Transport-Requests" are high only on 2 nodes

Tags: cassandra

We recently deployed micro-services into our production and these micro-service communicates with Cassandra nodes for reads/writes.

After deployment, we started noticing sudden drop in CPU to 0 on all cassandra nodes in primary DC. This is happening at least once per day. when this happens each time, we see randomly 2 nodes (in SAME DC) are not able to reachable to each other  ("nodetool describecluster") and when we check "nodetool tpstats", these 2 nodes has higher number of ACTIVE Native-Transport-Requests b/w 100-200. Also these 2 nodes are storing HINTS for each other but when i do longer "pings" b/w them i don't see any packet loss. when we restart those 2 cassandra nodes, issue will be fixed at that moment. This is happening since 2 weeks.

We use Apache Cassandra 2.2.8.

Also microservices logs are having reads/writes timeouts before sudden drop in CPU on all cassandra nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using token aware load balancing policy on client, and updating a single partition or range heavily. In which case all the coordination load will be focused on the single replica set. Can change your application to use RoundRobin (or dc aware round robin) LoadBalancingPolicy and it will likely resolve. If it does you have a hotspot in your application and you might want to give attention to your data model.

Comment: we're already using DC aware round robin policy. if application is updating single partition or range heavily then we should see high Native-Transport-Requests on the same node ips every time when we have this issue righ? but why do we see randomly 2 nodes (meaning first it's b/w NODE 1 &NODE 6, next time it is b/w NODE 2 & NODE 4 and so on) having high Native-Transport-Requests every time when we have this issue and why they're not seeing each other until we restart them?

Answer (score 0):

It does look like a datamodel problem (hot partitions causing issues in specific replicas).

But in any case you might want to add the following to your `cassandra-env.sh` to see if it helps:

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.max_queued_native_transport_requests=1024"`

More information about this here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11363

Comment: Thanks Carlos for your response. we already have that parameter in our cassandra-env.sh file with value 4096. JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.max_queued_native_transport_requests=4096". the part which I don't understand why only 2 nodes are not reachable to each other when we have this issue and those both nodes are storing hints for each other and when i do ping b/w them i don't see any packet loss and latency is less than 1 ms.

Comment: Are you experiencing big GC pauses or  high IO wait? What instance sizes are we talking about?

Comment: we are not experiencing bug GC pauses. i didn't check IO wait, i will check next time. we have 12 node cluster with 6 nodes in each DC. last week we increased memory on servers that are running micro-services and surprisingly from then we don't see outages.

Comment: we got this issue back after one month again, high "Native Transport Requests" thread count on 2 nodes and those 2 nodes are not seeing each other. any other recommendation please? I don't see GC pauses but when these nodes are going after having stuck "Native Transport Requests", i see at the same nodes which are running micro-services also went down and we noticed read time-outs in micro-service logs.